# TextBox of type Password is empty when printed in IE8

Tags: asp.net, printing, textbox, passwords

I have a form that has a textbox of type Password as a signature for the form. The user enters in their password to sign, thus the actual text should not be displayed but be dots. When printed, the textbox needs to still contain the dots to show that it has been signed. But when printed in IE 8 the box is blank. Firefox will print the dots but it needs to work in IE.

If it helps this is the basic textbox code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" textmode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't print `<input type="password" />` for security reasons. That said, typing something in a textbox isn't "signing" a document in pretty much every jurisdiction (just saying...).

I suggest you use Javascript to detect if the password field has text entered and add a message to that page that says it's been entered?

Comment: The page being printed is actually five iframes, each of a different page. Multiple pages have textboxes that need to be displayed. I don't think the Javascript solution will work for that. Is there anyway to have code that will send the page to some other program that will print the dots?